# how many request can be handled by Request.Files mvc asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maxrequestlength

When I uploaded about 18 files at a time the browser showed following error:

> Maximum request length exceeded.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length
>   exceeded.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum request length can be set in web.config . The default size is 4 mb.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded) for more details.